# C# Theoretical: Write a JMP to a codecave in asm

Tags: c#, assembly, codecave

Lets assume I've allocated the address where my codecave is placed using `VirtualAllocEx` (it returns the address) and I write my code into that address using `WriteProcessMemory()`.

Here's the question:

How do I write a jump to my codecave? I know that jumps start with "`E9`", but how do I convert the address returned by `VirtualAllocEx` into a correct UInt32 (dword) so the debugger/compiler will understand the instruction?

For example:

I'm at address `00402020` (OEP of the native app). I write a jump to `004028CF` (empty place) "`JMP 004028CF`". The instruction in bytes looks like this:

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Hex dump      Command                                  Comments
00402020  E9 AA080000   JMP 004028CF
```

"`E9`" is how we indicate a JMP. What about "`AA080000`", how do I generate this?

I need to do something similar so I can initialize a JMP to my codecave, which will be located at an address returned by `VirtualAllocEx()`.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the c# bit to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

E9 is a relative jump so the later 32 bits are just an offset to the current instruction pointer. See [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 2A: Instruction Set Reference, A-M](http://download.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253666.pdf) pages 549ff for details. For more information see [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/).

So the opcode to jump from 00402020 to 004028CF should be the following.

```
    E9  00 00 08 AA
```

```
Offset   = DestinationAddress - CurrentInstructionPointer
000008AA = 004028CF           - 00402025
```

When the jump instruction is executed, the instruction pointer is already set to the next instruction. So the offset of the jump instruction and the current instruction pointer value differ by 5.

```
CurrentInstructionPointer = AddressOfJumpInstruction + 5
```

**UPDATE**

Corrected error about the current instruction pointer value. Thanks jn.

Comment: I'm asking how to convert "004028CF" to "AA080000",How do I convert the destination address into those 32 bits so the instrction becomes valid?

Comment: You could have told me "Destination address -(minus) current address" instead giving me that pdf of 600 pages.However,As previously I mentioned,I appreciate any of your efforts,so I accept your answer.Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: what you are saying here is wrong! The correct formula for this case is: to - from - 5

Comment: If thought "E9 is a relative jump so the later 32 bits are just an offset to the current instruction pointer." clearifies the meaning. ^^ I was a bit confused about your AA080000 because it does not match the difference and I wanted to assert that I am right before I add an example.

Comment: Actually,you're wrong!Its AA,not AF.The jmp has length 5 bytes,it starts to count after those 5 bytes,so AF-5 = AA.
Correct? ;)

Comment: Thanks jn. Verified in the manual and updated answer. I have not done assembler coding for a while ... begining to forget and cannot rember what push SP pushes on the stack, too. SP or SP + 4?

Comment: ESP (on x86) always points to the last recently pushed item on the stack. When you push an item to the stack, ESP is decremented first, and then the parameter is stored at [ESP].

Answer (score 1):

to get the relative offset just subtract the addresses:

```
uint32_t patch_address = (uint32_t) VirtualAlloc(...);
uint32_t jmp_offset = patch_address - (current_offset + current_len);
```

note: current_len is 5 bytes on x86 E9 JMP instruction. see my post on this thread for more information:

[VirtualAlloc C++ , injected dll, asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242720/virtualalloc-c-injected-dll-asm/7004228#7004228)